# Styling Highcharts

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I'm trying to style highcharts spline chart, and I've got almost everything except that I can't modify spline to the way I want:

This is what I have: http://jsfiddle.net/6yzgD/

```
 plotOptions: {
            series: {
                color: '#fff'
            }
        }
```

... and this is what I want (spline dots are hollow) :

http://bit.ly/10SV7ek

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under your `series` options add the following `marker` options:

```
       series: [{
            name: 'Tokyo',
            data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6],
            marker: {
                lineWidth: 2,
                fillColor: '#e49d65'
            }
        }
```

Update [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6yzgD/1/).

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by important an image with the symbol you want

> symbol: String
>
> A predefined shape or symbol for the marker. When null,
>   the symbol is pulled from options.symbols. Other possible values are
>   "circle", "square", "diamond", "triangle" and "triangle-down".
>   Additionally, the URL to a graphic can be given on this form:
>   "url(graphic.png)".

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.marker

So you can save the circle in the form of an image, and pass that as the marker type.